# mamp to wordpress link issue

Tags: wordpress

I built this site on a local MAMP host. Now I uploaded the database - changed the config - find and replaced :8888 with .com in the database - uploaded the wp-content and the home.php page loads. hooray ! but the links are sending me to error. I tried every type of link I could think of. I'm stumped ! Any ideas ?

```
<ul>
<li><a href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/us" class="menu-about">about</a></li>
<li><a href="http://camandbenny.com/resumes" class="menu-resumes">resumes</a></li>
<li><a href="/work.php" class="menu-work">work</a></li>
<li><a href="books" class="menu-books">books</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/news.php" class="menu-news">news</a></li>
<li><a href="/contact.php" class="menu-contact">contact</a></li>
```

Comment: what kind of error?   link should be <?php echo home_url('/work'); ?>

Comment: sorry - the url is http://camandbenny.com/  --- thought i linked to it.

Comment: looks like htaccess issue (I'm posting suggested solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update permalinks.
Settings -> permalinks -> save changes

Ususally WordPress has no .php extensions.   I see news page is hardcoded to themes internal file... something is wrong here

Comment: i was just trying one type of link each because i was getting so confused.  your suggestion worked.  thank you.